# Accessing model in gensim wrapper

Tags: model, wrapper, gensim

I use following gensim wrapper to train a word-vector model:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gensim.sklearn_api import W2VTransformer
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess

# Load synthetic data
data = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/EPCmabvN')
data = data.head(10)
# Set random seed
np.random.seed(0)

X_train = data.apply(lambda r: simple_preprocess(r['text'], min_len=2), axis=1)
y_train = data.label

model = W2VTransformer(size=10, min_count=1)
model.fit(X_train)

model.wv.vocab
```

However, once I try to access the trained model, i.e. `model.wv.vocab`, it outputs the error:

> AttributeError: 'W2VTransformer' object has no attribute 'wv'

Can I somehow access the vocabulary and other model parameters, or is this not possible with the wrapper?

```
Current workaround: 

from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec

#Defining model without wrapper
documents = data.apply(lambda r: TaggedDocument(words=simple_preprocess(r['text'], min_len=2), tags=[r.label]), axis=1)
d2v = Doc2Vec(documents, window=2, vector_size=10, min_count=1, seed=0)
d2v.wv.vocab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think `W2VTransformer` has a `wv` property? It's not listed in the class docs:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/sklearn_api/w2vmodel.html

And, it's not quite idiomatic (within scikit-learn) to access a `Transformer`'s internal state like that. Instead, you would ask a model that's already been `fit()` to then `transform()` a list-of-words, to get back a list-of-word-vectors.

Indeed that's shown in the example at the top of those `gensim` docs, in a line which does both the `fit()` and `transform() in one line (even if you wouldn't want to do that):

```
wordvecs = model.fit(common_texts).transform(['graph', 'system'])
```

If you do want to access the native `gensim` `Word2Vec` model directly – a model which **does** have a `wv` property – you'd have to use a different approach. For example, you could review the `W2VTransformer` source code to see where that internal model is kept:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/sklearn_api/w2vmodel.py

There you would see that the `fit()` method stores the current `Word2Vec` instance in a property called `gensim_model`.

So, your line that is erroring, where `model` is an instance of `W2VTransformer`, could instead be:

```
model.gensim_model.wv.vocab
```

Comment: Thank you gojomo, I found it and it works. Excuse my gensim related questions, I am a starter and all the debugging and source code inspection is still a but new to me.